# User input of standard time converted into Julian Time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, julian-date

I'm stuck on how to get a users input of year, month, day and hour converted into Julian time.

This works if I code in the time like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from PyAstronomy import pyasl
import datetime


# Convert calendar date to JD
dt = datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 23, 10)
print("Input date: ", dt)
print("Corresponding Julian date: ", pyasl.jdcnv(dt))
print("Corresponding reduced Julian date: ", pyasl.juldate(dt))
print()
```

but when I try a users input like this

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from PyAstronomy import pyasl
import datetime

# Convert calendar date to JD

year = int(input('Enter a year'))
month = int(input('Enter a month'))
day = int(input('Enter a day'))
hour = int(input('Enter hour'))
dt = datetime.date(year, month, day, hour)
print("Input date: ", dt)
print("Corresponding Julian date: ", pyasl.jdcnv(dt))
print("Corresponding reduced Julian date: ", pyasl.juldate(dt))
print()
```

I get the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-4-2b1701814572> in <module>()
     11 day = int(input('Enter a day'))
     12 hour = int(input('Enter hour'))
---> 13 dt = datetime.date(year, month, day, hour)
     14 print("Input date: ", dt)
     15 print("Corresponding Julian date: ", pyasl.jdcnv(dt))
```

TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Check that datetime.date takes an hour. Normally a date doesn't go down to the hour (that would be a datetime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the wrong code in line in your second example:

```
dt = datetime.date(year, month, day, hour)
```

The correct is:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour)
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel really stupid for not catching that!  Thank you again